# No onClick() event for text-field (for specific sites)

Tags: javascript, qt, qtwebkit

### Background

I'm working on a custom browser implementation based on Qt 4.8 (QtWebkit 2.0). I'm trying to pop-up a virtual keyboard whenever the user clicks on a text field

- I have some simple JavaScript which adds a listener for a click event on any text field
- When a click is detected, it invokes a slot through the `myWebObj` object as shown below.

  ```
  $("input[type=text]").click(function() {
      var name = $(this).attr('id');
      alert("Text field " + 'id' + " clicked");
  });
  ```

### Problem

The code above works fine for most websites. For example it works for [How to Enter a Blocked Website](http://www.wikihow.com/Enter-a-Blocked-Website) and detects all the text fields.

However, for www.google.com, a click on the search bar doesn't invoke the click function.

Meanwhile on any standard browser like Firefox or Chrome the javascript given above works perfectly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `QtWebkit2.0` for portables... Maybe an problem in conflict with touch event? Maybe an bug in Jquery, try update Jquery... If not work try add use `touchstart`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento No bugs in jQuery, as i have tested for their correctness in Web Consoles. I'm not sure about the webkit problems when you port it. Thanks I will surely look into the touchstart thing.

Answer (score 1):

i had no problem in google.com but for apple you wont get it because their script is not your normal jquery. here is their $('selector') code

```
function $(element) {
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
        for (var i = 0, elements = [], length = arguments.length; i < length; i++)
            elements.push($(arguments[i]));
    return elements;
    }
    if (Object.isString(element))
        element = document.getElementById(element);
        return Element.extend(element);
}
```

you can check well what it does, but for your case i think your $("input[type=text]").click or $("input[type=text]").on('click', function should be completely ok.

For the virtual keyboard, you can try this: https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki

Comment: Thanks for the virtual keyboard link, I'll check it out, I wrote a VKB myself and had lot of coding to do for that and still it wasn't as good looking and as feature packed as the one you suggested. I don't know why but google.com's input tags aren't being recognized.